# Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python

Tags: python, pygame

```
DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
  bird_rect.centery += bird_movement
```

Comment: What is your question? I saw this too. It's simply a warning, and it won't stop your program from running.

Comment: Ignoring deprecation warnings is a recipe for a bad time.

Answer (score 3):

This is simply a Deprecation warning, and won't stop your program from running. All this is saying is that converting any variable to an integer with the `__int__` method will not be included in future versions of python. This is related to pygame only, though.

From what I can tell, somewhere in your code, you have this line:

```py
int(bird_movement)
```

When you blit that to an object, you get a floating point, which pygame does not consider a valid point. So pygame is just warning you, saying converting it to an integer with `__int__()` is deprecated and may not be allowed later.

So you don't have to worry, for now at least.

Answer (score 1):

`bird_movemen` seems to be a floating point value, but [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) can just store integral values, because the object is use for the pixel position of objects in the window. Track the position in an additional variable and `round` the variabel before the assignment to [`bird_rect.centery`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html):

Initialization

```py
bird_rect = pygame.Rect(....)
bird_centery = bird_rect.centery
```

movement:

```py
bird_centery += bird_movement
bird_rect.centery = round(bird_centery)
```